# adding 2 arrays to a new array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having difficulty adding arrays into another array without it merging all of the items inside of the array together. I've tried push and concat and they don't seem to do what I'm looking for.

```
var a = [1,2,3]

var b = [4,5,6]

result = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: `var b = [a,b,c]` <-- unless `a`,`b`, and `c` are variables and defined, this is a `ReferenceError`. They would also class with your array names

Comment: My apologise, Sterling, I've updated it to make it less confusing

Comment: `var result = [a,b];`

Comment: Your updated code runs fine in my console. Make sure `result` isn't global by using `var` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your new array based on your current variables like this:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];

var result = [a,b]; //Creates [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply add to an another array?

I.e  `var result = []; result.push(a);  result.push(b);`

Or just declare it as such:

```
 result = [a,b]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var a = [1,2,3]

var b = ["a","b","c"]

result = [a,b] // [[1,2,3],["a","b","c"]]
```

With [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3y4k6p1y/1/).

Answer (score 0):

use this way:

```
  var a = [1,2,3];
    var b = ['a','b','c'];
    var c =[];
    c.push(a);
    c.push(b);
    console.log(c);
```